# Can bad wheel bearing noise get louder with increasing outdoor temperature?

Tags: noise, temperature, bearing, rav4, wheel-bearing

I have self-diagnosed my RAV4 with a wheel bearing going bad.  One thing I noticed:

- During height of the day (10 am to 6 pm), when hottest: bearing scratching/grinding noise is loudest
- Otherwise: bearing noise isn't as loud

Does this match anyone else's experience? Does it make sense that increasing outdoor temperature can correspond with louder bearing noise?

I am wondering if this can help me further understand the noises my car can make.

---

My inclinations the wheel bearing is bad:

- Scratching/grinding noise starts at ≥30 mph (if hot outside) or ≥55 mph (if cold)
- Hitting brakes doesn't seem to affect the noise
- It continues for the entire drive (not a function of short or long drives)
- Car is a 2008 Toyota RAV4 with >200k miles,
  and I have beaten it up over the years

Full disclaimer: noise could be coming from brakes, I may be wrong in my self-diagnosis

Comment: How did you diagnose a faulty bearing? Is there play on the wheel?  How do you know the noise is not coming from the brakes?

Comment: Note that the humidity is also likely changing along with the temperature.

Comment: Also, if this is actually a bad wheel bearing, you're usually able to feel it in the steering wheel and body before you hear it. Once you can hear a wheel bearing, it's usually best to get it fixed before you drive it anymore. When a wheel bearing gets noisy, failure is usually immanent.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, I have updated the original post with details of my car, and I am now questioning my self-diagnosis of wheel bearing issue.  Let me know what you think, if you have time

Comment: Have you checked for play in the bearing yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from my single data point, it turned out both of my rear wheel bearings were bad. Using both a stethoscope (for noise) and hand test (for play), bad wheel bearings were diagnosed. Since replacing them both together, all noise has stopped.

So, now I believe that the noise from a bad wheel bearing can increase with increasing outdoor temperature. This belief is backed by my personal experience with my rear wheel bearings going bad.